# Какие шаблоны проектирования нужны вдобавок к "репозиторию" для удаления, добавления и обновления сущностей?

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования

Если класс, написанный согласно шаблону проектирования "Репозиторий" выдаёт сущности конкретного вида (одну, несколько или все), то написанные согласно каким шаблонам ещё нужны классы для добавления, удавления и обновления сущностей?